# Updating textbox from different classes in the application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I read many similar posts here but I still have some questions regarding not only how to accomplish this but if there is a better or more appropriate way to accomplish this. This being that I have a WPF application in which I have a Main window that instantiates a page object called ScratchPad that contains a textbox and a method to update the contents of that textbox.

```
public partial class MainWindow
{ 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ScratchPad scratchPad = new ScratchPad();
    }
}
```

Here's the associated XAML that also instantiates(?) my other applications in frames within the MainWindow.

```
 <DockPanel>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem Header="Main">
            <Frame Source="Common/GUI/ScratchPad.xaml" ></Frame>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test Apps">
            <Frame Source="Apps/TestApp/View/authPrompt_View.xaml" Margin="0,0,0,191.2" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Threads">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

This object is intended to display log materials to report on the status of operations the application performs. The code for ScratchPad can be seen below.

```
public partial class ScratchPad : Page
{
    public ScratchPad()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void updateStatus(string newText)
    {
        scratchPadTextBox.AppendText(newText);
    }
}
```

My intention is to have many of my other classes be able to append to that textbox, however I believe in order to do this I would need to pass a reference to the MainWindow object to each of the classes that want to write to that textbox. My problem is that the other classes are not directly instantiated (to my knowledge) and as a result I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this or even if this is how it should be done. Here's a sample of a class that I would like to be able to append to the textbox which is created when the user hits submit on a page that is instantiated(?) through a frame source in the MainWindow's XAML.

```
    class ConnectionManager
    {
    public void authenticateSharePoint(string urlAddress)
    {
        DataContextRef.DataContextRefDataContext dc =
            new DataContextRef.DataContextRefDataContext(new Uri("redacted.svc"));

        dc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; var source = dc.Test;
        ((System.Net.NetworkCredential)dc.Credentials).Domain = "blah";
        ((System.Net.NetworkCredential)dc.Credentials).UserName = "blah";
        ((System.Net.NetworkCredential)dc.Credentials).Password = "hardcodeisthebest123";
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            scratchPad.updateStatus("item.name: " + item.Name);
            updateStatus("item.title: " + item.Title);
            updateStatus("item.path: " + item.Path);
            updateStatus("item.id: " + item.Id);
        }
    }
```

As seen in the XAML above copied again below, this class is created when a user selects the submit button in a separate class that is hosted in a frame in the MainWindow

```
    <TabItem Header="Test App">
        <Frame Source="Apps/TestApp/View/authPrompt_View.xaml" Margin="0,0,0,191.2" />
    </TabItem>
```

As is always the case, when I type out my issue I realize just how many areas I need to address from a knowledge gap perspective. Any insight and/or assistance is appreciated!

Comment: In theory, 1. use Event to send the message from one view to another view. Or 2. simply refers/ syncs the property to observe second views' ViewModel's property.

Comment: U can make something similar to this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482545/how-do-i-notify-a-parent-view-of-a-child-view-event-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/43488052#43488052 where your TPayload can be <string> and that textBox can subscribe on multiple publishers, from other childViews

Comment: As stated, your question is too broad. But, certainly the first place you should start is to **stop manipulating the `scratchPadTextBox` element directly**. Your code should have a view model, with a `string` property representing the text to display, bound to the text box's `Text` property, and any changes to the text should be made through the view model, rather than the text box directly. The text box should not even need a name. How best to then expose that view model property to other types is debatable, especially given the lack of context above. But that's a much simpler problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I believe Peter is correct in that I should be using a view model class to manipulate the view and that is the paradigm in the rest of my code. Once that's done, I'll look into both methods proposed by Kurakura88 and Ivica to see which one works best for me. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however I believe in order to do this I would need to pass a reference to the MainWindow object to each of the classes that want to write to that textbox.

You could get a reference to the existing instance of the `MainWindow` using the `Application.Current.Windows` collection:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
if(mainWindow != null)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why the two responses got downvotes this exactly answers one of the questions I asked above!

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access your main view's object you have to create an instance of it from the class you want to access it from.

```
       ScratchPad name = new ScratchPad();
```

Now you should be able to access the scratch pad with something like :

```
     name.updateStatus.scratchPadTextBox
```

Comment: I do create an instance of it but I do not want to create multiple instances of the object. Once the MainWindow class instantiates the object I want the other classes to be able to manipulate the already created object. I believe Peter Duniho above mentioned the correct approach so I'll fix my current code and see where I'm at from there.